# Multiple meta_query not working

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I try to get woocommerce product by customfield and thumbnail, this code is working fine:

```
foreach ($result as $v)
                                {$product = array
                                    (
                                        'post_type' => 'product',
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                                        'meta_query' => array
                                        (
                                            //'relation' => 'OR',
                                            array(
                                                    'key' => 'product_cip',
                                                    'value' => $v,
                                                    'compare'=> '=',

                                            ),
                                            array(
                                                    'key'=>'_thumbnail_id',
                                                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        'fields' => 'ids'
                                    );
                                    $product_post = get_posts($product);
                                    //echo $product_post[0].', ';
                                    $a[] = $product_post[0];
                                    //echo count($product_post);}
```

But return only products with image. I need to return products with image first and after the other products.

I'v tried this:

```
foreach ($result as $v)
                                {$product = array
                                    (
                                        'post_type' => 'product',
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                                        'meta_query' => array
                                        (
                                            'relation' => 'OR',
                                            array
                                            (
                                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                                array
                                                (
                                                    'key' => 'product_cip',
                                                    'value' => $v,
                                                    'compare'=> '=',
                                                ),
                                                array
                                                (
                                                    'key'=>'_thumbnail_id',
                                                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                            array
                                            (
                                                array
                                                (
                                                    'key' => 'product_cip',
                                                    'value' => $v,
                                                    'compare'=> '=',
                                                ),
                                                array
                                                (
                                                    'key'=>'_thumbnail_id',
                                                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                        'fields' => 'ids'
                                    );}
```

But the page never load and cursor wheeling...

Thanks

EDIT: add AND

```
foreach ($result as $v)
                            {

                                $product = array
                                (
                                    'post_type' => 'product',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                                    'meta_query' => array
                                    (
                                        'relation' => 'OR',
                                        array
                                        (
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array
                                            (
                                                'key' => 'product_cip',
                                                'value' => $v,
                                                'compare'=> '=',
                                            ),
                                            array
                                            (
                                                'key'=>'_thumbnail_id',
                                                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                        array
                                        (
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array
                                            (
                                                'key' => 'product_cip',
                                                'value' => $v,
                                                'compare'=> '=',
                                            ),
                                            array
                                            (
                                                'key'=>'_thumbnail_id',
                                                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    'fields' => 'ids'
                                );}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this kind of query is super expensive and with a lot of products will be super super slow

Comment: And check the syntax

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks, yes I see this is more than super expensive because there block the page... :-) Maybe you know a different method to do this ?

Comment: Meta queries can't be made fast, you'd have to refactor your data storage to use taxonomies for searching and filtering. It also looks like your check for thumbnail id is unnecessary as you check for both when it exists and when it doesn't exist. Consider using a custom taxonomy for `product_cip`